# JSON for FHIR Patient LIST

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I created an FHIR server using the HAPI FHIR libraries.

I can now send JSON FHIR objects for a single Patient Resource.

Ex.

```
baseurl/patient/123456
```

Now I have to send multiple Patient Resources.

Ex

```
baseurl/patient/clinic_id
```

1. Can I Use the **FHIR bundle resource** ***or*** a **simple JSON array** of Patient Resources?
2. Does HAPI FHIR supports sending multiple Patient Resources as a JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAPI would support using Bundle.  A simple JSON array would not be FHIR conformant.

Comment: In addition to that, please read the http://hl7.org/fhir/http.html page to make your server conform to the FHIR RESTful API.